# Is there an Java library for sending binary data over HTTP, HTTP Tunneling?

Tags: java, http, http-tunneling

I would like to send quite large chunks of data in a binary format over HTTP, also called [HTTP Tunneling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_tunnel).

I would like to use this technique using Java for a few Java Swing applications and maybe an Android application. Is there any good Java libraries for HTTP Tunneling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JHttpTunnel](http://www.jcraft.com/jhttptunnel/)

Answer (score 3):

Here is another implementation in [Jodd](http://jodd.org) library. There is base implementation named [`HttpTunnel`](http://jodd.org/api/jodd/http/HttpTunnel.html). Here is a simple example how to use it:
https://github.com/oblac/tools/blob/master/src/jodd/tools/http/TinyTunnel.java

Answer (score 1):

HttpURLConnection. No need for another library.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use Apache Commons HTTP library to send HTTP.