# Reverse Tunnel over JSCH (SSH) and HTTPS

Tags: java, apache, ssh, https, http-tunneling

I have to implement a reverse tunnel from client to server. I have used [JSCH](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) with the following command

```
session.setPortForwardingR(rport, lhost, lport);
```

and it works (see also [Reverse SSH tunnel with JSCH Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27883491/reverse-ssh-tunnel-with-jsch-java?rq=1))!

next I have to tunnel my ssh session over an HTTPS stream 2-way authenticated:

> ```
> client -> firewall -> apache https -> ssh server 
>
> ----------------------> HTTPS
> ====================================> SSH
> ---------------------->
> ```

I'm looking for

1. a small piece of java code to encapsulate SSH into HTTPS
2. 2 way HTTPS authentication
3. APACHE configuration

possible solution:

### 1) HTTPS Tunnel

1. [JHTTPTunnel](http://www.jcraft.com/jhttptunnel/), but it is based on J2ME and it doesn't support SSL (see also [Java Http Tunneling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586728/java-http-tunneling/4586943#4586943) , [Is there an Java library for sending binary data over HTTP, HTTP Tunneling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042573/is-there-an-java-library-for-sending-binary-data-over-http-http-tunneling/4042623#4042623))
2. [JOD](http://jodd.org/), but it doesn't support SSL

### 3) APACHE CONFIGURATION

1. Maybe this [configuration](http://mark.koli.ch/configuring-apache-to-support-ssh-through-an-http-web-proxy-with-proxytunnel) works but I have to try

> ```
> ## Load the required modules.
> LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
> LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
>
> ## Listen on port 8443 (in addition to other ports like 80 or 443)
> Listen 8443
>
> <VirtualHost *:8443>
>
>   ServerName youwebserver:8443
>   DocumentRoot /some/path/maybe/not/required
>   ServerAdmin admin@example.com
>
>   ## Only ever allow incoming HTTP CONNECT requests.
>   ## Explicitly deny other request types like GET, POST, etc.
>   ## This tells Apache to return a 403 Forbidden if this virtual
>   ## host receives anything other than an HTTP CONNECT.
>   RewriteEngine On
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^CONNECT [NC]
>   RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ - [F,L]
>
>   ## Setup proxying between youwebserver:8443 and yoursshserver:22
>
>   ProxyRequests On
>   ProxyBadHeader Ignore
>   ProxyVia Full
>
>   ## IMPORTANT: The AllowCONNECT directive specifies a list
>   ## of port numbers to which the proxy CONNECT method may
>   ## connect.  For security, only allow CONNECT requests
>   ## bound for port 22.
>   AllowCONNECT 22
>
>   ## IMPORTANT: By default, deny everyone.  If you don't do this
>   ## others will be able to connect to port 22 on any host.
>   <Proxy *>
>     Order deny,allow
>     Deny from all
>   </Proxy>
>
>   ## Now, only allow CONNECT requests bound for kolich.com
>   ## Should be replaced with yoursshserver.com or the hostname
>   ## of whatever SSH server you're trying to connect to.  Note
>   ## that ProxyMatch takes a regular expression, so you can do
>   ## things like (kolich\.com|anothersshserver\.com) if you want
>   ## to allow connections to multiple destinations.
>   <ProxyMatch (kolich\.com)>
>     Order allow,deny
>     Allow from all
>   </ProxyMatch>
>
>   ## Logging, always a good idea.
>   LogLevel warn
>   ErrorLog logs/yourwebserver-proxy_error_log
>   CustomLog logs/yourwebserver-proxy_request_log combined
>
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution proposed by yourself is ok it is based on [Implement HTTPS tunneling with JSSE](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077475/core-java/java-tip-111--implement-https-tunneling-with-jsse.html) I think.

the basic steps are:

1. define your connection factory for JSCH
2. open a SSL Socket and call   `"CONNECT " + host + ":" + port`

on server side catch all request calling the "CONNECT" and enable 22 SSH port.

But you have also to consider the following issues:

1. tune the timeout because the SSL handshake is quite long
2. enable 2-way authentication or all people can connect to 22 of your server:
   [Using client/server certificates for two way authentication SSL socket on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064810/using-client-server-certificates-for-two-way-authentication-ssl-socket-on-androi)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunatly no any one has tried to reply; I found the solution.

The solution is based on the [HTTP 1.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) `CONNECT` command and doesn't support direct tunnel.

## On the Java client

> ```
>          // Install the all-trusting trust manager
>          final SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
>          sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
>          JSch jsch = new JSch();
>          Session session = jsch.getSession("root", "SSH-server", 22);
>
>          session.setSocketFactory(new SocketFactory() {
>           Socket tunnel = null;
>
>           public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
>
>               SSLSocketFactory ssf = sc.getSocketFactory();
>
>               // HTTP
>               tunnel = ssf.createSocket(System.getProperty("https.proxyHost"), Integer.getInteger("https.proxyPort"));
>               tunnel.setKeepAlive(true);
>
>               doTunnelHandshake(tunnel, host, port);
>               System.out.println(tunnel + " connect " + tunnel.isConnected());
>               return tunnel; // dummy
>           }
>
>           public InputStream getInputStream(Socket socket) throws IOException {
>               System.out.println(tunnel + " getInputStream " + socket.isConnected());
>               return tunnel.getInputStream();
>           }
>
>           public OutputStream getOutputStream(Socket socket) throws IOException {
>               System.out.println("getOutputStream");
>               return socket.getOutputStream();
>           }           });
>
>       session.connect();
>
>       try {
>           session.setPortForwardingR(3391, "localhost", 3389);
>       ....
> ```

where

> ```
>   private static void doTunnelHandshake(Socket tunnel, String host, int port) throws IOException {
>         OutputStream out = tunnel.getOutputStream();
>         String msg = "CONNECT " + host + ":" + port + " HTTP/1.0\n" + 
>        "User-Agent: " +
>        sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.userAgent + "\r\n\r\n";
>         byte b[];
>         try {
>
>               b = msg.getBytes("ASCII7");
>         } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ignored) {
>               /*
>                * If ASCII7 isn't there, something serious is wrong, but Paranoia
>                * Is Good (tm)
>                */
>               b = msg.getBytes();
>         }
>         out.write(b);
>         out.flush();
>
>         /*
>          * We need to store the reply so we can create a detailed error message
>          * to the user.
>          */
>         byte reply[] = new byte[200];
>         int replyLen = 0;
>         int newlinesSeen = 0;
>         boolean headerDone = false; /* Done on first newline */
>
>         InputStream in = tunnel.getInputStream();
>         boolean error = false;
>
>         while (newlinesSeen < 2) {
>               int i = in.read();
>               if (i < 0) {
>                     throw new IOException("Unexpected EOF from proxy");
>               }
>               if (i == '\n') {
>                     headerDone = true;
>                     ++newlinesSeen;
>               } else if (i != '\r') {
>                     newlinesSeen = 0;
>                     if (!headerDone && replyLen < reply.length) {
>                           reply[replyLen++] = (byte) i;
>                     }
>               }
>         }
>
>         /*
>          * Converting the byte array to a string is slightly wasteful in the
>          * case where the connection was successful, but it's insignificant
>          * compared to the network overhead.
>          */
>         String replyStr;
>         try {
>               replyStr = new String(reply, 0, replyLen, "ASCII7");
>         } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ignored) {
>               replyStr = new String(reply, 0, replyLen);
>         }
>
>         System.out.println(replyStr);
>
>         /* We asked for HTTP/1.0, so we should get that back */
>         if (!replyStr.startsWith("HTTP/1.0 200")) {
>               throw new IOException("Unable to tunnel for " + host + ":" + port + ".  Proxy returns \"" + replyStr + "\"");
>         }
>
>         /* tunneling Handshake was successful! */
>   }
> ```

## On the apache configuration

add the ssl support

> ```
>  SSLEngine on
>  SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"
>  SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl.key/server.key"
> ```

here the result

```
Connecting to localhost port 22
HTTP/1.0 200 Connection Established
....
Authentications that can continue: password
Next authentication method: password
Authentication succeeded (password).
Connected
```